# Rails - Has many through with values on join table, how to efficiently do this for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a marking application that allows teachers to mark students submitted work against outcomes.

A submission can either partially meet, or fully meet the outcomes.

So SubmissionX could fully meet Outcome1, partially meet Outcome2 and not meet Outcome3

So the tables look roughly like this:

**Submission**

id

title

....

**SubmissionOutcome**

submission_id

outcome_id

partially_met (true / false)

fully_met (true / false)

**Outcome**

id

title

.....

I am displaying a list of all the outcomes in the course. And the teacher can check if an outcome has been partially met or fully met.

Because I am adding extra information to the join table (partially or fully met) I am currently looping through each of the outcomes, if the submission doesn't belong to that outcome I am building it:

```
  def initialized_submission_outcomes(unit:, outcome_group: )
    [].tap do |o|
      unit.outcomes.where(outcome_group: outcome_group).find_each do |outcome|
        if submission_outcome = this_submissions_current_outcomes.find_by(outcome: outcome)
          o << submission_outcome.tap {|submission_outcome| submission_outcome.enable ||= true }
        else
          o << SubmissionOutcome.new(outcome: outcome)
        end
     end
  end
```

end

and then tidying up the returned params in the controller in a before_action:

```
    params[:submission][:submission_outcomes_attributes].values.each do |evidence_attr|
       evidence_attr[:_destroy] = true if (evidence_attr[:enable] != '1' && evidence_attr[:partially_met] != '1')
    end
```

This is turning into a nightmare for n+1 problems. Some courses can have 400 outcomes so it's taking ages (25 secs + ) to load the form.

I would love it if someone could point me to a more efficient way to tackle the problem.

Many Thank

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your tables, but to avoid looping through the outcomes you can use a SQL query in select.

```
select_query = 'outcomes.*, case when <your logic here> then true as partially_met, case when <your logic here> then true as fully_met'

Outcome.joins(:submissions).group('outcome_id').select(select_query)
```